# Launching Varying Vagrant Vagrants with a custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, vagrant-provision

not sure if anyone has tried this yet but I want to setup VVV for my team and then pull in our custom theme from our bitbucket repository. I have the working curl command to pull our repo, and I am wondering where to plug this in so it will run automatically when I call "vagrant up". I was thinking the init.sh file for the default wordpress website it creates, but it doesn't seem like anything I put in there is running. Anyone else tried to do something like this?